Подключение сторонних библиотек QT c++ на линуксе
Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку gisdesigner.
Вот так выглядит мой про файл
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

# здесь нужно указывать путь до заголовочных файлов, используемой библиотеки
# внутри должна быть куча хэдеров
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/gisdesigner

# нужно указать путь до библиотеки, причем внутри папки с библиотекой должны лежать .so файлы (аналог dll на винде)
# -L путь где лежат все библиотеки; -l пошли конкретные библиотеки
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/gisdesigner/qt5 -lmapcomponents -lqdmapobj -lqdmapscena

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

При переходе в /usr/include/gisdesigner

При переходе в /usr/lib/gisdesigner/qt5

Создал тестовый код для проверки подключения библиотек и поймал ошибку, библиотеки не подключились, подскажите, пожалуйста что я делаю не так?


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Ну так еще раз посмотрите на структуру заголовочных файлов и на то, как вы их пытаетесь подключать.

Взять в кавычки?

В папке, которую вы добавили в INCLUDEPATH, нет ни mapcomponents, ни mapcomponent.h

У gisdesigner есть масса примеров, они обычно лежат /usr/share/gisdesigner/examples/, вот pro файл проекта mapview:
QT += core gui

QT += widgets

TARGET = mapview

TEMPLATE = app
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath-link,$(GISDESIGNER_ROOT)/usr/lib 

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    mapwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    mainwindow.h \
    mapwidget.h

FORMS += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += $(GISDESIGNER_ROOT)/usr/include/gisdesigner

LIBS += -L$(GISDESIGNER_ROOT)/usr/lib -lqdmapacces

